# Error when restoring SQL Server 2008 R2 backup on 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore

I am trying to restore a .bak file (backup taken on SQL Server 2008 R2, compatibility level 100). I am restoring the backup on SQL Server 2012 edition. I get the below error. Unfortunately the original DB from where the DB was backed up is no longer available. Any suggestions on how I can restore the DB to 2012 ?

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Read on *** failed: 13 (The data is invalid.) (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: Which version (build) and edition of SQL server 2012? Are you restoring a database from the enterprise edition on standard edition? Also please try to upgrade to the latest service pack of 2012 - I had a funny issue like that once. But it still looks like the medium is flawed.

Comment: I would suggest taking another backup, to a different drive than where you took the original, and restoring it from a different drive, too.

Answer (score 1):

Do a Restore Headeronly With File = '...'  If it still fails it's not a valid native SQL Server backup file. It's not an issue of versions.

Open it with a hex or text editor, what's the file header look like? Maybe it's compressed with a 3rd party solution like LiteSpeed and those require you to use a tool to convert to native format if you don't have it installed in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fairly ominous for you I'm afraid. Likely an issue with data integrity or the validity of your drive.

http://www.sqlserverf1.com/tag/restore-database-is-terminating-abnormally/

Comment: Restore failed on a 2088 r2 version too. I am trying to restore 2008 r2 o a 2012 enterprise edition

Comment: I have opened a support ticket with Microsoft. Hopefully will find some answer